# Template Meta-programming, with Variadic Templates: compiler error

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm attempting variadic template meta programming for the first time and consistently getting a compiler error that I have not been able to track down.

I'm following the "tuple" example on [this page](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/) (although I'm calling my object an `ItemSet`)

The `ItemSet` part compiles just fine:

```
template<typename...Ts> class ItemSet { };

template<typename item_T, typename ...Ts>
class ItemSet<item_T, Ts...> : public ItemSet<Ts...>
{
public:
    ItemSet(item_T t, Ts... item_types) : ItemSet<Ts...>(item_types...), tail(t) { }

protected:
    item_T tail;
};





template <typename...M> struct type_holder;

template<typename T, typename ...M>
struct type_holder<0, ItemSet<T, M...>>
{                          // ERROR: M parameter pack expects a type template argument.
    typedef T type;
};

template <int k, typename T, typename ...M>
struct type_holder<k, ItemSet<T, M...>>
{
    typedef typename type_holder<k - 1, ItemSet<M...>>::type type;
};




int main()
{
    ItemSet<int, string, string, double> person(0, "Aaron", "Belenky", 29.492);
}
```

However, in the commented out code, I get the compiler error at the declaration of type_holder.
I've tried a bunch of variations on the same syntax, but always with the same issue.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, which is *supposed* to have full support for Template programming and Variadic Templates.

Do you understand what the compiler error is, and can you explain it to me?

Comment: add missing primary template `template<int, class T> struct type_holder;` and fix typo `typeholder` -> `type_holder`

Comment: Updating the question as the answers suggested, but still have a different error....

Comment: what *different error* ?

Comment: "the compiler error" is extremely vague. Most compilers have several hundred, if not thousands of different error/warning messages they might produce. Don't make us guess which one you're getting...

Comment: now you are missing `int` in your primary template, follow [Dietmar Kühl's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27487598/3953764) answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you are defining a specialization of `type_holder` without a general template. In addition, there is a simple typo (`typeholder` instead of `type_holder`). Fixing these two issues makes it compile with other compilers:

```
template <int, typename T>
struct type_holder;

template <int k, typename T, typename ...M>
struct type_holder<k, ItemSet<T, M...>>
{
    typedef typename type_holder<k - 1, ItemSet<M...>>::type type;
};


template<class T, class ...M>
struct type_holder<0, ItemSet<T, M...>>
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

The error emitted by the compilers you used isn't particular helpful. I'd recommend keeping a few C++ compilers around just to test template code with (I'm typically using [`gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/), [`clang`](http://clang.llvm.org/), and [Intel's compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers)).

Comment: do you want someone™ to try that with visual c++ 2013?

Comment: primary template could have only one type-parameter, not an entire pack

Comment: This one seems to work.  Thanks!
It'll take me a bit of careful comparison to figure out where it is substantially different from my own code.

Comment: @abelenky: I just added a primary template declaration (`template <int, typename> struct type_holder;`) and change one `typeholder` to `type_holder`.